# Merging different numbers of Xpath nodes using xmllint

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have a file having data as follows:

```
       <root>
         <x>
            <y lang="en">
              <z>1</z>
              <z>2</z>
              <z>3</z>
              <z>4</z>
              <t>5</t>
            </y>
          </x>
          <x>
            <y lang="en">
              <z>a</z>
              <z>b</z>
              <t>c</t>
            </y>
          </x>
       </root>
```

I would like to print them as follows

1 2 3 4 5

a b c

The first one has 4z and 1t and the second one has 2z and 1t.  Since xargs is not static I can not print them as I want.  I tried a script as follows $f being the file:

```
xmllint --xpath "//root/x/y/z/node() | //root/x/y/t/node()" $f | xargs -n2
```

What I get as a result is:

1 2

3 4

5 a

b c

If you would have any ideas I would be happy.

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Comment: `xmllint` requires valid XML.

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert on XML. What do you mean by valid XML? I am sure my file is valid since I can work on it. But I can't share the file so I shared a similar structure.

Comment: What @Cyrus means is that the XML needs to be wrapped in a root element. Also, there's a simple solution using xpath 2.0, but xmllint doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks Jack! I updated the example by adding the root. If there is any other solution beside xmllint then maybe I could change my tool as well.

Comment: If you can change your tool, I would use xidel which supports xpath>1.0.

Comment: and which function would allow me to do that. I am unaware of how I can do that even if I change the tool. If you could reference me any page I could look then I would be happy.

Comment: See answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xidel file.xml -e '//x/string-join(./y/*/.," ")'
```

The output I get with your xml:

```
1 2 3 4 5
a b c
```

Comment: Thanks Jack this worked great! So string-join is the xpath 2.0 function I assume, right?

Comment: @Erwarth Exactly.

Comment: I think your xpath could be simplified to `//y/string-join(*,' ')`

Comment: Or even `//y/join(*)`, where [`join()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-join) is a shorthand for `string-join(...," ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [`sel` (select) option of xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416)...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//y" -v "normalize-space()" -n input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xmllint --xpath "//x/y/*/node()" $f | xargs -n2
```

Comment: Thanks, William. This has the same problem as mine. It concatenates as two arguments which is the result of xargs -n2. But my file has different numbers of z.